# TeamCity using MSDeploy 401 Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, teamcity, msdeploy

I have written a small powershell script for TeamCity to call msdeploy.exe

The problem I am having is when TeamCity executes my script (below) I get a 401 unauthorized error. The trouble I am having is that I know for a fact this is the correct username and correct password - I even tried making the password something as simple as 'password' just to prove I was not typing it incorrectly.

I read in some places that it could have to do with the site name, but if I access the msdeploy url with ?site=test, I am able to log in with the credentials. Am I missing something in my script? Did I forget something somewhere else?

```
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";
$site = "test"
$msdeployUrl = "https://someserver:8172/msdeploy.axd?site="
$user = "correct username"
$password = "correct password"
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy    V3\msdeploy.exe";
$msdeployArguments = 
'-allowUntrusted:true',
'-source:contentPath="D:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\e5be789e2c46e6c4\v1\web\"',
('-dest:auto,computerName="'+$msdeployUrl+$site+'",includeAcls="false",userName="'+    $user+'",password="'+$password+'",authtype="Basic"'),
'-verb:sync',
'-disableLink:AppPoolExtension',
'-disableLink:ContentExtension',
'-disableLink:CertificateExtension'
'-setParam:name="IIS Web Application' + ('Name",value="' + $site + '"');
Write-Host $msdeployArguments
& $msdeploy $msdeployArguments
```

Comment: As a test, can you try running MSDeploy directly from the commandline on the build server?  Instead of through TC.

Comment: @chief7 Error: Source does not support parameter called 'IIS Web Application Name'. Must
 be one of ().

I get this error when running directly

Comment: I'm able to connect now, I removed the user and added it. I am able to connect but it does not push any files to the server

Comment: Does it throw an error?  If that package has already been deployed then there are no new files to publish.

Comment: No error - just that 0 files were updated. I'm not using a package though, I'm just trying to sync a folder

Comment: Have you previously synced that folder?  By default, MSDeploy only deploys changed files - http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/03/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-only-deploy-changed-files/

Comment: Nope, there was some older code there but it was outdated by at least two weeks. I switched from the MSDeploy URL to a directory and it synced up everything just fine. I'm going to need to get the URL working though so I can sync to another server

Comment: Can you use the -verbose flag and provide the msdeploy output in a gist?